# Apache tika not able to extract width and height for svg file

Tags: java, svg, apache-tika

I am using Apache tika library to extract metadata for files like width and height.  Here is my code snippet

```
public void fileMetadata(final File file) {
         FileMetadataModel fileMetaData = null;
        var context = new ParseContext();
        var parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        var bodyContentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        var metadata = new Metadata();
        try (final var openInputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(file)) {
            parser.parse(openInputStream, bodyContentHandler, metadata, context);
            // metadata extration 
            ..........
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
}
```

Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I see for SVG file it doesn't give image height and width. Is there any way to get it through Apache tika?

Comment: Quite a lot of svg files might not contain any width/height info at all: Ideally you could retrieve size info from the parent svg tag: `<svg width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 200">...</svg>` . If you can parse the svg's xml you might get the size from width/height or viewBox (actually rather the proportion: 3. and 4. values are width and height) attributes.